# batch file-count the number of files copied over

Tags: batch-file

I'm using xcopy to copy over a folder to another, and I use /d command to copy files from last modified. And I want to log the number of files copied every time. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Call `xcopy` two times: first with the `/l` option and redirect the output to a file `xcopy /l [...] >list.log` and second the usual command without `/l`.

Comment: Thanks and a follow up. When I tried the >x.log together with /-y, the display yes/no options were hidden. how do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

read `HELP XCOPY` and then use `XCOPY /L /Q` command to achieve what you want.

or alternatively, I would use `ROBOCOPY` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy